# Getting a unique id after biometrics authentication in flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, biometrics

In flutter, the [local_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_auth) plugin provides a way to authenticate users using biometrics. But it only returns a `Future<bool>` response:

```
var localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
bool didAuthenticate =
    await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance');
```

I wonder if there is any way to retrieve some unique **ID** to know which user has logged into the system.

**EDIT:** In android, after authentication it returns a [`BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult.html) object which contain a MAC id. I am looking for something like that in flutter.

Comment: Hi, have you got your answer? Looking for the same thing.

Comment: Did anyone manage to get an identifier using flutter yet? Maybe its not possible in iOS, but on Android? Been looking for the same.

Comment: No. The biometrics authentication does not work like that. It can only verify whether the user is authentic or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are implementing the unique with biometric. But here is the plugin which is a unique id provider based on a device.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/unique_id

Have a look

Very lightweight plugin, single line code for getting the unique id

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want to identify users differently as they log in using biometrics. Many users can enter via same device, and I want to defer these users by some id.